# can't get hamburger menu to hide based on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to have the hamburger menu hide when screen width is over 400px.

Here is a link to the site damf.co

You will notice that when the screen width is less than 400px the hamburger appears, if you click on it then have the window expand I cant get the window to hide therefor pushing the content to the side and not being able close it again until the screen is under 400px.

I am quite new to this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems fine on my end. As soon as you change the browser size, it pops closed. I can't recreate your problem.

Comment: Being new, your code is really clean. I would check out codekit and SASS while you are at it. Cheers for not going with bootstrap. You'll be way better off in the long run.

Answer (score -1):

To be totally honest, there are not going to be any practical users that will open that menu, expand the window, and then afterwards try to close it. If you really want to prevent that you could probably bind a 'resize' event to your js code. I don't know what you're using, but something like that might fix it.

I really don't think you need to worry about it though.